If I vibrate an object at a high enough frequency, is it "hot"?
Let's take a (10cm)³ cube of steel as our reference object.
Heat is just atoms vibrating within our cube of steel. Apply more heat, get more vibration; the two are the same.
If we have a good enough off-balanced motor, like a rumble pack, and place our cube upon it and turn on the motor to vibrate the whole cube, why isn't the cube "hot"?
I'm not referring to internal deformation or air friction or anything like that; I'm asking: what is the qualitative difference between the atoms of an object vibrating rapidly, and the entire object vibrating rapidly?
If I placed my hand on a very hot cube, I would expect to receive a severe burn.
If I place my hand on a cube vibrating very quickly, I would not expect to receive that burn.
But physics tells us that these two concepts are actually the same; just vibrations.
What am I missing?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413097/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173362/2451 and links therein.

Edited to clarify; I don't believe my question is a duplicate.

I feel like the "violently shaking object" question you linked (second link) gets close to what I'm asking, but I'm not sure if it's quite there as it's referring to imparting kinetic energy into the atoms in the water; I'm asking about the motion of an object gestalt.

Same amount of energy gets converted to heat, but when you rub two sticks together you're both doing more work (since you're increasing the friction force by pushing the sticks together for a stronger normal force, while also then moving fast back and forth), and concentrating the area in which the movement gets converted to heat. As you go through the air the heat gets dispersed through a large volume of air molecules (which also then cool by convection) instead of a small area of stick molecules when you rub.

Check the Joule experiment. Shaking, stirring, in general, applying some work to a piece of material does indeed heat it. However, the amount of energy you can impart by this method is generally very small, even in the ideal situation where all the mechanical energy gets dissipated into heat. If you get a 100 W motor that moves in and out of a line, attach it to a bottle full of water, and let it run for 10 minutes (equivalent of you shaking), at most that'll deliver 60 kJ. The heat capacity of water is 1 calory per gram per kelvin. What that means is all this energy can only be used up 1.5 kg of water by 10 degrees. And even that won't happen, because:

The motor may draw 100 W, but the actual mechanical motion will have a lower power (there's power dissipated in the mechanical and electrical components).

The water will dissipate heat as it's shaken, meaning the end temperature will also be lower.


